# Safest way to initialize double variable in java

Tags: java, double

I used to initialize double variables with `Double.NaN` and fill them later depending on the input. If there were mistakes in inputs I just return `Double.NaN`. This practice backfired, when other part of application used my function as input and worked just OK, doing basic arithmetic and comparing `NaNs` with double (but didn't supposed to, I would expect exception).

The obvious solution would be to add `Double.isNaN()` at the end of my code and throw exception inside my function
But this is a highly used function in highly optimized code, so I'm unwilling to add extra check each time it is called. I would rather prefer break the whole application on wrong parameters once a year than add an extra check, esp. I heard that comparing to `NaN` takes longer than comparing to double. How do I achieve that and  what are best practices in this situation?

**EDIT** 
for example, I want to return first parameter for parametric function which I know nothing about depending on user input

```
private double getFirstFactor(HashMap <String, Double> userParams) {
   double res = Double.NaN;
    if(userParams.containsKey("factor1")) {
        res = userParams.get("factor1");
    }
    return res;
}
```

Usage

```
double f1 = getFirstFactor(userParams);
double threshold =  f(f1); // for example f1 * 100 + f1; 
// ideally, code above breaks if f1 is not defined and I don't go futher
if(threshold >= 0) {
...
} else {
...
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you've got something very wrong with your design. You need to show your code and how you're initializing and using the variable if you want any suggestions.

Comment: Whats wrong with using ``null`` as a default value for a ``Double``? Why ``NaN``?!

Comment: @f1sh Not `Double`, `double`.

Comment: @Kayaman but why? When you need a type that can hold a value that represents a "there is no value"-state, use the wrapper type and set it to ``null``.

Comment: @f1sh That's not always an option. If you look at the "this is a highly used function in highly optimized code" part, you can understand why switching to wrapper may not work.

Comment: @Kayaman but NaN is not a constant that represents a missing value. You can still use ``==`` for instance.

Comment: @f1sh I never claimed it is. I'm not the one needing clarification here.

Answer (score 3):

Don't do that.

`NaN` is used for the result of certain expressions (e.g. `0.0 / 0.0`) and has the *unique* property that it compares false with itself.

You should *always* initialise `double` values with something sensible. Depending on your algorithm, `0.0` and `1.0` are often good values.

If you *really* can't do that then you could always use a `Double`, with `null` as your default-initialised value.

Comment: I added an example as requested
If i don't know inputs and possible usage of output it's kind of difficult to come up with sensible..

Comment: In which case you might as well use `Double` and `null`: looking up from a hash map is not particularly cheap - the bottleneck will never in using a boxed type despite your protestations that this code is "highly optimised".

Comment: just tried to come up with simple example (no Hashmaps in code)
which is better - using Double or adding additional check Double.isNaN ?

Answer (score 2):

You should always validate your inputs before using them. If your inputs are invalid, you can throw an `IllegalArgumentException` before any computation is done at all. It makes it the caller's responsibility to use your code with correct inputs.

It's always better to fail fast, instead propagating invalid values throughout your system. This can cause big problems (as you probably have experienced).

Answer (score -1):

Use boxed type `Double` and use `null` as default value insteed of `Double.NaN`. If I would need to stick to primitives, I would got for `0.0d` as default value.

Comment: You can't do that for the primitive type, but it's a good idea for the boxed analogue.

Comment: @Bathsheba well, OP is not specifying if he use primitve or boxed type, but he strongly suggests that he uses boxed one, as he wants to use  `Double.NaN` for it.

Comment: @Antoniossss `Double.NaN` is a `double`, not a `Double`.